# Loading script depending on userinput

Tags: powershell, scripting

Hi im fairly new to the whole scripting scene and was hoping somebody could help me. I've created a menu which depending on user input will prompt an answer back, but i need to make it so if you press "1" it will load another script into this script and so on
my current code is this :

```
function Show-Menu
{
     param (
           [string]$Title = 'Menu'
     )
     cls
     Write-Host "           $Title          "

     Write-Host "1: Tast '1' for at oprette OU"
     Write-Host "2: Tast '2' For at oprette grupper"
     Write-Host "3: Tast '3' For at importere brugere i grupper"
     Write-Host "4: Tast '4' For at eksportere brugerlister til CSV"
     Write-Host "5: Tast '5' For at slette brugere"
     Write-Host "6: Tast '6' For at ændre password"
     Write-Host "Q: Tast 'X' For at afslutte."
}
do
{
     Show-Menu
     $input = Read-Host "Please make a selection"
     switch ($input)
     {
           '1' {
                cls
                'Du valgte Nummer #1'
           } '2' {
                cls
                'Du valgte Nummer #2'
           } '3' {
                cls
                'Du valgte Nummer #3'
                } '4' {
                cls
                'Du valgte Nummer #4'
                } '5' {
                cls
                'Du valgte Nummer #5'
                } '6' {
                cls
                'Du valgte Nummer #6'

           } 'q' {
           cls
           'Afslutter nu'
                return
           }
     }
     pause
}
until ($input -eq 'q')
```

any tips on how to load scripts into this script is appreciated

- Phillip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, don't use `input` as a variable name - `$input` is an [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) and you may end up seeing some weird and unexpected behavior by attempting to overwrite it.

For "loading" scripts, use the [dot sourcing method](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847841.aspx), as follows:

```
. C:\path\to\script.ps1
```

The above will execute script.ps1 in the calling scope, so all variable and function definitions in the script is available afterwords:

```
do
{
     Show-Menu
     $choice = Read-Host "Please make a selection"
     switch ($choice)
     {
        '1' {
            cls
            'Du valgte Nummer #1'
            . C:\path\to\script1.ps1
        } 
        '2' {
            cls
            'Du valgte Nummer #2'
            . C:\path\to\script2.ps1
        } 
        '3' {
            cls
            'Du valgte Nummer #3'
            . C:\path\to\script3.ps1
        } 
        # og så videre ...
        } 
        'q' {
            cls
            'Afslutter nu'
                return
        }
     }
     pause
}
until ($choice -eq 'q')
```

Finally, you may want to go for either only Danish or only English text in the output, but that's more of a pet peeve on my part :-)

Comment: Thanks and yeah it should be all danish dont know why i decided to input it in english XD